# How to switch sources on jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, plugins, autocomplete

I am writing a plugin to do tags like on stack overflow. Now I have got the plugin more or less working, apart from one problem I haven't worked out. I either want to take my source from an object or a url. Not at the same time of course. So I would like to switch them, but you can't put an if statement inside the autocomplete plugin, and I am not sure if I can build the source lines before I run the autocomplete.

So I either want my source to be taken from settings.avalableTags or from the url code I have underneath. Is there any way to switch these, either before the autocomplete or inside.

Here is my code.

```
$(idtag).find('input').autocomplete({
  //source: settings.availableTags,
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: settings.url,
      data: $.extend(settings.data, {
        'term': $(idtag).find('input').val()
      }),
      dataType: 'JSON',
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        response(data);
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    idtag = "#" + id;
    $(idtag).find('input').val(ui.item.label);
    base.addTag();
  },
  change: function(event, ui) {
    if (!ui.item) {
      $(this).val('');
    }
  }
}).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 188) {
    $(this).blur().val('');
  };
});
```

I tried Mohammed's suggestion. Now if I set availableTags(false) it works, but doesn't work when I change to true. So it isn't running my function correctly. I believe it is because I can't put in the request/reponse needed to post eg

```
var availableTags =function (condition){
    if(condition){
        return settings.availableTags
    }else{
        $.ajax({ url: settings.url,
        data: $.extend(settings.data,{'term': $(idtag).find('input').val()}),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            return response(data);
        }
    });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally have the answer that works.

```
var availableTags =function (request, response){
    if(settings.url==""){
        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(settings.availableTags, request.term));
    }else{
        $.ajax({ url: settings.url,
        data: $.extend(settings.data,{'term': $(idtag).find('input').val()}),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){response(data);}
        });
    }
}
```

and then in the autocomplete it has to be like this

```
base.autocomplete= function(){
    $(idtag).find('input').autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event,ui){
        id=$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        idtag="#"+id;
        $(idtag).find('input').val(ui.item.label);
        base.addTag();
},snip...
```

Basically if I send a url into the plugin it runs the ajax code, but if I don't send in a url it defaults to the tags.
eg if i send in this, it will run the local tags

```
$('[data-asitag]').asiTag({availableTags:[{label:"Action",value:"1"},{label:"Apple",value:"2"},{label:"Aferburner",value:"3"}],force:false});
```

but if I send in this

```
$('[data-asitag2]').asiTag({
        url: 'ajax/ajax.php',       
        force:true});
```

It will send in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to the

```
source: functionName()
```

So you can put whatever business you want including the

```
 if ()//Statement
```

Have a look [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8vHNywYAm8WavIYkei6n?p=preview)

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried your suggestion from the example. I can get one to work, but I can't get my url code to work. I wonder if you could show me how you would do it. I have edited my post to show what I tried